# Rails: routes.rb and omitting the controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

From Hartl's Rails Tutorial Book, some routes for static pages are [automatically generated](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#code-pages_routes):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get  'static_pages/home'
  get  'static_pages/help'
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

Why do the 'home' and 'help' routes not have the controller#action?
E.g. `get 'static_pages/home', to: 'static_pages_controller#home'`

The closest documentation of this I could find was in the the Rails Guides routing page's [static segments section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments).

Comment: I think rails will take care of 'static_pagesr#home' part automatically as long as your url 'static_pages/home' matches 'controllername/action' pattren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing through some documentation, and finding nothing relevant, I had a look at the source. It seems that the `match` method (which `get` is a shorthand for) is calling `get_to_from_path` (defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1645)), which extracts the controller and method information from the provided `path`, if `to:` isn't provided.

So, for this scenario, this

```
get 'static_pages/home'
get 'static_pages/help'
```

gets mapped to `static_pages#home`, and `static_pages#help`. Using dashes (`-`) instead of underscores (`_`) in the path would work as well.

It is weird that this functionality is not documented, and more so that it is used in a tutorial without explanation.

Comment: My motivation for the post was to see if anyone else could find documentation, but providing the source code for the behavior is satisfactory for me.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The routes</strike>

```
get  'static_pages/home'
get  'static_pages/help'
```

do not have a controller/action associated with them because the contents of those pages are not generated dynamically from the controller. They are most likely defined on the file system at `public/static_pages/home` and `public/static_pages/help`. The public directory can be used to serve static content directly without using controllers.

Edit:

If static_pages does refer to a controller then most likely Rails is able to derive the name of the controller and the name of the action when you create a route of the form `<name of controller>/<name of action`. Rails just assumes that the left hand side of the "/" is the controller and the right hand side is the action.

Comment: In the linked tutorial, the page is described to be mapped onto a controller just like a normal route.